# Is there any Open topic Classifier API for demo purposes

Tags: classification

Is there an Open Classifier/Categorizer API which returns categories/topics for a given entity string. For example for an input string like : "Barack Obama" it should return topics like : "Politics" similarly for "Albert Einsten" it should emit "Physicist, Nobel Laureate" etc.

Answer (score 0):

try [texlexan](http://texlexan.sourceforge.net/). it gave me some really good results but with slightly longer input texts.